# Transferring files fast between pc and AVD

Tags: android, adb, android-virtual-device

I have to copy some external files from my pc to my AVD. It seems that's possible, specifically through the ADB using this command: `> adb push "C:/_tmp_filestocopy" "/sdcard"`, and it's copying right now, but at a rather slow speed, and when I say rather slow, I mean **extremely** slow. For example, a 50MB file cost me slightly less than 20 minutes. My question, therefore, is: ***is any faster method available to transfer files from PC to AVD***? I've read somewhere that you can mount the `sdcard.img` from the AVD in Linux. Unfortunately, I'm running Windows. Perhaps I can try VirtualBox or VMWare now or then. Also, I've seen Quick ADB Pusher, but I suspect it just uses the ADB commandline, but with a GUI. Is it actually quicker, or is it just commandline behind a GUI?

Comment: I use email for most of stuff :))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try the following:

> 1) Create an sdcard image file when setting up the android emulator. Make sure the file is big enough to store all the data you want the emulator to access.
>
> 2) Mount the sdcard image file on Windows ( just like you would mount a ISO image ). Check this link http://heatware.net/windows-xp/how-to-mount-an-isobinuifimg-image-in-windows/
>
> 3) After doing this, you should have some sort of external or virtual disk accessible from your file browser.
>
> 4) Copy all your stuff to the virtual image.
>
> 5) Unmount the image from the system.
>
> 6) Fire up the emulator. It should see all the data on the sdcard.

On GNU/Linux would be much easier, since you can mount/unmount the img with one command.

Good luck!